# zip extraction, have `-d` ingnore one level zip folder structure (CLI)

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a file `My_big_zip_file.zip` with the following file structure:

```
unzip -l My_big_zip_file.zip
```

yields:

```
Archive:  My_big_zip_file.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
155274931  2018-01-16 14:30   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201501).zip
 96693995  2018-01-16 13:50   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201403).zip
113751167  2018-01-16 14:10   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201409).zip
158758696  2018-01-16 14:16   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201410).zip
140706108  2018-01-16 13:24   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201308).zip
142957976  2018-01-16 14:51   My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201505).zip
---------                     -------
808142873                     6 files
```

I want to unpack this content all in `/results/` but when I run

```
unzip My_big_zip_file.zip -d results
```

I get one unwanted folder level:

```
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201501).zip  
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201403).zip  
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201409).zip  
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201410).zip  
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201308).zip  
  inflating: results/My_big_zip_file/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201505).zip
```

so how to avoid having `My_big_zip_file/` in the output path? e.g. make the result be:

```
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201501).zip
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201403).zip
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201409).zip
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201410).zip
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201308).zip
results/Level1_BasicFile_ProductID(254)_Date(201505).zip
```

Comment: So you're looking for [Equivalent to tar's “--strip-components=1” in unzip?](https://superuser.com/questions/518347/equivalent-to-tars-strip-components-1-in-unzip) - AFAIK it doesn't (yet) exist

Comment: @steeldriver: wao thanks! I felt so dumb for banging my head on this.

Comment: Don't feel dumb - it's a good question (else why would the implementors of `tar` consider it worth adding)

Comment: In any case, your link solved the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2413 Considering that your question is solved with what has been linked, it's a duplicate and therefore can be closed as such if you have no objections of course

Comment: Ah, nevermind - it is on superuser not our site

Comment: @steeldriver  Think you can write an answer for this one ?

Comment: @user2413 The following might be what you are after: `unzip My_big_zip_file.zip 'My_big_zip_file/*' -d results` ?

Comment: @user2413 I have tested this fairly extensively and sometimes for reasons I cannot clearly see the `-j` option is also required. I will flesh this out to a full answer if there is further interest in this question :)